# How to find the basis of this eigenspace?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $\lambda$ is 2 and after calculating $A-\lambda I$, $$\left(\begin{array}{rrr} -2 & 0 & -2\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).$$

The reduced row echelon form is: $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).$$

The solution is actually: $$\left(\begin{array}{aaa} 0\\ 1\\ 0 \end{array}\right).$$ and

$$\left(\begin{array}{bbb} 1\\ 0\\ -1 \end{array}\right).$$

Can someone explain how the book arrived at this?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} \iff \begin{cases} x+z=0 \\ 0=0 \\ 0=0\end{cases} \\ \iff \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{-z \\ y \\ z} = y\pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0 }-z\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ -1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenspace is the null space of the  system $(A-2I)X=0$. If you are familiar with finding a basis for the solutions of a homogeneous system, that alone will do.

Notice we have two linearly dependent columns. This gives us two basis vectors for the solution.

In particular, you can read off the first row of the reduced form as

$x+z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the eigenvectors of $A$. For eigenvector $\lambda=2$, this corresponds to finding the vectors $v$ such that $Av=2v$ which is the same as $Av=2Iv$, where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity. Subtract and you get $A-2I=0$. So you take that first matrix you listed, which is $A-2I$, and row reduce with zeros on the other side. Your second matrix is saying that $x+z=0$, or $x=-z$. So you have a free variable $z$. Thus, the eigenvectors for $\lambda=2$ are of the form $(-z,y,z)$ where $y$ is any real number. If $z=0$, then $z=-z$ and we have $(0,y,0)$. Your author chooses $y=1$ arbitrarily. If $z\neq 0$, then we factor it out $z(-1,\frac{y}{z},1)$. Here your author chooses $y=0$ arbitrarily.